# How can I convert audio files to this format?

Tags: macos, wav, audio-conversion

I have a bunch of audio files that are named .wav but it seems not all .wavs are created equal.  For example:

```
$ file *
file1.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, stereo 44100 Hz
file2.wav: Audio file with ID3 version 2.2.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 160 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo
file3.wav: Claris clip art?
file4.wav: Audio file with ID3 version 2.2.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 160 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo
```

And for good measure, a non-wav:

```
file5.m4a: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, iTunes AAC-LC
```

I would like to convert all of these files to the format that file1.wav is:

```
RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, stereo 44100 Hz
```

What is the proper set of arguments to pass to `afconvert` to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your file2.wav and file4.wav are .mp3 files

maybe you should separate them by type first and then try the conversion from the different types to real .wav  (PCM uncompressed)

i believe you cand find a tutorial here:
http://blog.bitcomet.com/post/103259/

If you really MUST use afconvert, make sure that your files have the proper extensions for their format.

Comment: Well, I have a lot and more will come so it needs to be automatable.  I was using afconvert because its a command line tool and its there.  If there is a better tool I'd happily use it.  But GUI tools (I looked at another one that was on the Vorbis wiki—I forget the name) are not going to work.

Comment: try something like this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271354/how-do-i-use-afconvert-to-convert-all-the-files-in-a-directory-from-wav-to-caf